# Conditional update pulling from another table - Access syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am a beginner with MS Access.

I have two tables - *workrelationship* gives dates for every time a person worked for the organization (we apparently terminate and rehire a lot), and *workterms* gives start/stop dates for every time something changed in the system for an employee - new address, name change, etc. So there can be multiple *workterms* periods in a *workrelationship* period.

There's a column *POS* (period of service id) in *workrelationship* that I need to copy into *workterms* for every wt date range that falls within a *wr* date range. I then need to delete every row in *workterms* where the dates don't fall into a *wr* range.

There are ~50k rows in *workterms* and I need to get this right, so I set up sample tables in Access to play with. [Here's a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iPkRLkE57uV3AsbOhTBrz5_SSKbhxoS_X1gPGayLJI/pubhtml#) to the two tables and the error message (see below).

My plan is to pull in the POS first and mark anything that isn't bounded by workrelationship dates "delete". Then I can do a delete on every row that says "delete" in the *POS* column. (`DELETE FROM workterms WHERE pos = 'delete';`)

I am getting a [syntax error in Access](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iPkRLkE57uV3AsbOhTBrz5_SSKbhxoS_X1gPGayLJI/pubhtml#) when I do the first part:

```
UPDATE workterms
SET wt.pos =
    CASE WHEN (wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart 
    and wt.termend <= wr.finalend) 
    THEN wr.pos
    ELSE 'delete' 
    END
FROM workterms wt
INNER JOIN workrelationship wr
ON wr.personid = wt.personid
```

Any ideas on the syntax error? It's highlighting the word "WHEN" on row 3. I'm not familiar with Access but I have been searching and this looks right compared to what I've found.

EDIT: I tried `IIF` too:

```
UPDATE workterms
SET wt.pos =
    IIF ((wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart 
    and wt.termend <= wr.finalend), wr.pos, 'delete')
FROM workterms wt
INNER JOIN workrelationship wr
ON wr.personid = wt.personid;
```

EDIT 2: HansUp's query below ran just fine (thanks!!), which takes care of the syntax problem.

```
UPDATE workterms wt
    INNER JOIN workrelationship wr
    ON wr.personid = wt.personid
SET wt.pos =
    IIF(
        wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart AND wt.termend <= wr.finalend,
        wr.pos,
        'delete'
        );
```

EDIT 3: But - [it only brought 3 values in](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iPkRLkE57uV3AsbOhTBrz5_SSKbhxoS_X1gPGayLJI/pubhtml#), where I'm expecting 8, as you can see by the select below and the "SELECT from EDIT 3" tab in the linked spreadsheet:

```
SELECT wr.*, wt.*
FROM workrelationship wr, workterms wt
WHERE wr.personid = wt.personid 
and wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart 
and wt.termend <= wr.finalend
```

Comment: `CASE ... WHEN` is not supported in Access SQL.  Check out `IIf()` instead.  Also, for a valid Access `UPDATE`, you will need to move the entire `FROM` ahead of the `SET` --- but not actually include the keyword `FROM`.  I'm confused by point #2, so can't say more.

Comment: Looks like this query is just made to change a field to say "delete" then later she would run a query to `delete all where field = delete`.  Seems like she wants to change this query to just do the delete with one step. More like `delete all where termstart >=originalstart`, at least that is what it seems to say.

Comment: Yes @Newd - but it's ok if I can't do that. I can get the job done by marking for deletion and then deleting in a second step. #1 is my main issue.

Comment: @HansUp - I tried replacing the case statement with IIF ((wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart and wt.termend <= wr.finalend), wr.pos, "delete"), and I am still getting a missing operator syntax error. Thanks you guys, for the ideas, I've been banging my head against the wall for a while on this.

Comment: re: SSMS - See if you have "Import Data..." under Tasks when you right-click on a database like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UkUDH.png).

Comment: Should I open a new question? Sorry, I'm new - I'm just trying to make this work - your code fixed the syntax error but it's still not bringing back the expected data.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks, and yes I did try that yesterday but it was a little more complex going through the process and I can't even remember what tripped me up, but I couldn't pull the CSV files in as easily as I could in Access.

Comment: @HansUp "A nice long `drink` will help." FTFY.  @AmyC can you edit your post with the 8 records you were expecting and which three were actually affected?

Comment: Sure @Newd, it's here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iPkRLkE57uV3AsbOhTBrz5_SSKbhxoS_X1gPGayLJI/pubhtml# under the last 2 tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current UPDATE query is not giving you the results you desire because the INNER JOIN is only being done on [personid]. So for any [personid] that appears more than once in [workrelationship] your UPDATE query is generating multiple conflicting results.

Consider the following SELECT query that mimics the behaviour of your UPDATE query for [personid]=2:

```sql
SELECT 
    IIF(
        wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart AND wt.termend <= wr.finalend,
        wr.pos,
        'delete'
        ) AS result,
    wt.personid,
    wt.termstart,
    wt.termend,
    wt.pos AS wt_pos,
    wr.originalstart,
    wr.finalend,
    wr.pos AS wr_pos
FROM 
    workterms wt
    INNER JOIN 
    workrelationship wr
        ON wr.personid = wt.personid 
WHERE wt.personid = 2
ORDER BY wt.termstart, wr.originalstart
```

The results are

```
result  personid  termstart   termend     wt_pos  originalstart  finalend    wr_pos
------  --------  ----------  ----------  ------  -------------  ----------  ------
200-1          2  2010-02-01  2010-03-01  blah    2010-02-01     2010-05-01  200-1 
delete         2  2010-02-01  2010-03-01  blah    2010-07-01     2010-10-01  200-2 
200-1          2  2010-03-01  2010-05-01  blah    2010-02-01     2010-05-01  200-1 
delete         2  2010-03-01  2010-05-01  blah    2010-07-01     2010-10-01  200-2 
delete         2  2010-07-01  2010-10-01  blah    2010-02-01     2010-05-01  200-1 
200-2          2  2010-07-01  2010-10-01  blah    2010-07-01     2010-10-01  200-2
```

Notice that each [workterms] row appears twice, once for each corresponding row in [workrelationship], and the [result] is different depending on which [workrelationship] row is joined. So your UPDATE query will actually update each [workterms] row twice. The final value of wt.pos will be whichever value gets applied last, and the order in which the updates are applied is completely up to the query optimizer.

So what you need to do is apply the updates in two passes. Start by setting all wt.pos values to 'delete'

```sql
UPDATE workterms SET pos = 'delete'
```

and then update the wt.pos values for the eight (8) rows you want to keep by using a query that joins on both the [personid] values *and* the dates:

```sql
UPDATE 
    workterms wt
    INNER JOIN 
    workrelationship wr
        ON wr.personid = wt.personid 
            AND wt.termstart >= wr.originalstart 
            AND wt.termend  <= wr.finalend
SET wt.pos = wr.pos
```

Now your [workterms] table will look like this:

```
personid  termstart   termend     pos   
--------  ----------  ----------  ------
       1  2010-08-01  2010-09-01  100-1 
       1  2010-03-01  2010-05-01  100-1 
       2  2010-07-01  2010-10-01  200-2 
       2  2010-03-01  2010-05-01  200-1 
       2  2010-02-01  2010-03-01  200-1 
       3  2010-11-01  2015-12-01  delete
       3  2010-09-01  2010-10-01  300-2 
       3  2010-08-01  2010-09-01  300-2 
       3  2010-07-05  2010-07-15  delete
       3  2010-05-01  2010-07-01  300-1
```

Comment: "So your UPDATE query will actually update each [workterms] row twice." - I should have realized this when it told me that it was going to update 23 rows on a table of 10 records (a few had 3 matches instead of 2). This is great, @GordThompson, thank you so much... this works perfectly!!!